# Exctracting competitor numbers from photos

Tags: opencv, ocr

What kind of open source or low end solutions there would exist to extract (marathon) runner's numbers from photos?

A small photo studio is asking whether there would exist an automated solution cheap enough for them to use. They need to tag competitors in several thousand of photos.

Comment: can you give sample images if possible? 
also pls see link in comments to peakxu's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Tesseract-OCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) engine?

Comment: don't think that would work for scene text - i.e. where the text is part of a scene image of athletes, T-shirt folds, etc. Use of any text extractor from natural scene images with a subsequent Tesseract operating on those identified text-bearing regions should give better results

Comment: something like this is already done: https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~meam620/wiki/index.php?n=MenglongZhu2011.Final